# Template type deduction in a simple datatype

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create a datatype that supports integers and floating points and that will deduce the type during construction.

The code below compiles, but I would like to modify it so that the 3 commented lines will compile instead.

Is this possible in C++98?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Result
{
public:
    Result(std::string name, T value) : m_name(name), m_value(value) { }     

private:       
    std::string m_name;
    T m_value;
};

int main()
{
    Result<double> hello(std::string("Test"), 123.45);

    //std::vector<Result> results;
    //results.push_back(Result("Test Int", 32));
    //results.push_back(Result("Test Double", 42.1));

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

I just want to be able to store results in a vector, the result type will have a name and a value. The value may be an int or a float. Other than that I don't really care how the class is defined or how it's instantiated.

Comment: I think you misplaced the brackets... `results.push_back(Result("Test Int"), 32);` should be `results.push_back(Result("Test Int", 32));`. And the next line too.

Comment: `std::vector<Result> results;` will be still invalid even in C++20

Comment: You pass no template argument to result in std::vector<Result>

Comment: @LuisGP Thanks, I fixed it

Comment: How would the compiler be able to deduce the template arguments for `Result`in `std::vector<Result> results;`? That's impossible that way.

Comment: In short: `Result<double>` and `Result<int>` are completely different types, you cannot store them in the same vector. You would need type erasure.

Comment: I added an edit to clarify what I'm asking

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in C++98 since [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) is not supported there.

**Considering C++17 from now:**

Also here, the compiler cannot deduce the template arguments for `Result` in `std::vector<Result> results;`. It's impossible that way. Just imagine that line on its own - how would you possibly be able to deduce any type without some value to deduce it from?

However, if you know if advance which elements you want to insert into your vector (or at least the first one), you can let the compiler deduce all arguments by calling something like:

```
std::vector results { Result("Test Int", 32) };
```

Note that in your example, the second insertion has a `double` type (as compared to `int` above) , so you won't be able to push it into your vector.

In case you need to store different types, have a look at `std::variant` or `std::any` (but that's another story).

Answer (score 0):

After your edit, I think the easiest way is to store pointers instead instances. You cannot create pointers to a template class, but you can create an interface to use it in the vector:

```
class IResult {...};
```

And then Result must inherit from it.

```
template <typename T>
class Result : public IResult
{
...
```

Finally, the vector will be declared with IResult instead of Result pointers.

```
std::vector<IResult*> results;
results.push_back(new Result<int>("Test Int", 32));
results.push_back(new Result<double>("Test Double", 42.1));
```

Just remember that you must free that memory by yourself.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid specifying <int> and <double>, but this is pretty close to what I want. Thanks!

Comment: std::vector<Result*> results; will result in a compile error saying "template argument 1 is invalid"

Comment: `Result` is not a type but a class template. You cannot form pointers to class templates.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to avoid the template class pointer. Thanks!